# Is there a way to use a 4th generation ipod touch with broken LCD... like from your computer?

Tags: lcd, ipod, ipod-touch

My friend gave me a broken iPod that he found and I'd like to mess w/ it before I fix it, like possibly see who owns it, and see if they want it before I fix it.

I was wondering if there's a way I can output the display because the LCD (back-light) is cracked, yet the glass is perfect, so I'm assuming digitizer (touch screen part) would still work if I could just see what it's trying to display.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try plugging it into a computer yet?  What happened?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, there isn't any type of terminal which will allow you to display an iDevice on your computer. However, you can just plug it into your computer and iTunes should still recognise it and show you most of the details.

Also, there is a piece of software called [DiskAid](http://www.digidna.net/diskaid) which will allow you to see much more information than iTunes displays without having to jailbreak the device.

You'll be able to find all the information you'd need by using these programs. However, if the device has a pascode on it there's not really much you can do as it will prevent the computer from accessing the device.